# Does having a result that is "robust to specification" make it more likely to be true?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, robust, misspecification

I'm wondering if there is any evidence (simulated or otherwise) demonstrating that robustness to specification actually means a result is more likely to be true.  By robustness to specification I mean that a particular relationship is found to be significant (e.g. gun ownership increases suicide) across a wide-variety of specifications (e.g. whether you include certain controls or exclude them, whether you log certain variables, whether you include square terms, and so on).

Researchers use this kind of argument as if it demonstrates we can be more confident in a particular result. It strikes me that it is entirely plausible for a result to be true given the "correct specification", but to disappear across numerous other specifications (and thus not be robust).  I'm wondering if robustness to specification actually increases the predictive validity of a model, and how we can know that robustness to specification means a result is more likely to be true than a result which is highly sensitive to specification.

I would be particularly interested in simulated evidence showing that robustness to specification doesn't increase the probability of finding the "true relationship."

Comment: Please edit your question to include a definition of the term "robust to specification".

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is to minimize the model errors. There is always a risk of misspecification. The misspecification of variables is very common indeed. So, when you see that you're getting similar results with different specifications of the variables, it gives you a level comfort around the conclusions you made. You could actually attempt to quantify the model error this way.

This is used a lot in practice. You have to make a decision based on the data. For instance, you need to allocate the loss reserve against the loans. What if your model is wrong? So, you'd add up the model error buffer to the loss reserve. And by looking at the variance of results on different specifications, you could come up with an appropriate buffer.

Comment: I understand all of this.  My question was for a formal proof (or simulated demonstration) of the following claim: " it gives you a level comfort around the conclusions you made."  I'm wondering if the subjective level of researcher comfort actually maps onto something meaningful; e.g. does having a result robust to model specification actually mean that your result is more likely to be true?  If so, how do we know this?"

Comment: In the context that I gave you, there cannot be a formal proof. The whole idea's about [unknown unknowns](https://academic.oup.com/jxb/article/60/3/712/453685), they can't be simulated. It doesn't mean that someone didn't try to simulate them in a different context

Comment: So when you say that "it gives you a level of comfort around the conclusions you made", I'm wondering why this is true.  If it's impossible to know that a result that is robust to specification is more likely to be true than a result that is highly sensitive to specification, why should you be comforted in this fact?

Comment: Because it reduces my expert judgement based estimate of the model error. If by changing the specs I get about the same result, then it must be that my model error is low. It also goes to the idea of replication is science: if two researchers got the same result by different means then we tend to trust the results more

Comment: Couldn't it also mean that you have failed to include some relevant co-variate?  Let's say that the "true" data-generating procedure for the suicide rates in a state is defined by: `suicide ~ gun_ownership + state_GDP + public_welfare_expenditure + alcohol_rates + unemployment_rate`

In my model, let's say I forget to include "unemployment" and find gun_ownership doesn't increase suicide.  I show this is "robust to specification" because I can also leave out "state_GDP", or add in squared "alcohol_rates", etc.  In this case, robustness to specification doesn't mean my model error is low

Comment: Yes, but it's not a fair comparison. You should compare it to the situation where you try gun_onwership variable in two different specifications, maybe per household vs. per capita, and get totally different results. This would throw a shade on the outcome. In science you can't prove that the model is correct, but you can prove it's wrong. Your situation is tough because you deal with observational social study. Basically, whatever conclusion you come to is probably wrong anyways, because you're not controlling for something. You need an experiments to resolve this, at least natural one

Comment: Right, I'm referring to social studies, which is usually where this phrase is deployed. It sounds like you're saying what I suspect is true -- e.g. we have no formal guarantee that a result which is "robust to specification" is actually more likely to be true than a result which is "highly sensitive to specification."  Would you agree with that?

Comment: Of course, I agree. There cannot be a formal proof of the statement. There could be simulation and empirical studies at best.